# How to stop (clearInterval) setInterval per button click

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 boxes, first blue box must start moving arrow up, which works fine, and I want the second yellow box to pause arrow, but I couldn't make it happen. Thank you for suggestions.

**http://jsfiddle.net/Km7nw/3/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box1').click(function () {
       setInterval(function(){
          $('.arrow').css("top", "-=20px");
       }, 400);

       //clicking on box2 must clearInterval

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var interval; 
    $('.box1').click(function () {
       interval = setInterval(function(){
          $('.arrow').css("top", "-=20px");
       }, 400);       
    });

    $('.box2').click(function () {
       clearInterval(interval);      
    });    
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Km7nw/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure variable to store the reference to the interval

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval;
    $('.box1').click(function () {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            $('.arrow').css("top", "-=20px");
        }, 400);
        //clicking on box2 must clearInterval
    });
    $('.box2').click(function () {
        clearInterval(interval)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qj6Vu/)

Answer (score 1):

Use  [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval)  function.

```
clearInterval(intervalID)
```

> intervalID is the identifier of the repeated action you want to cancel. This ID is returned from setInterval().

So,we create id  *i*  from  `setInterval`  method and passing it to `clearInterval`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var idToClear;
    $('.box1').click(function () {
        idToClear = setInterval(function(){
          $('.arrow').css("top", "-=20px");
       }, 400);
       //clicking on box2 must clearInterval
    }); 

     $('.box2').click(function () {
      clearInterval(i);
    }); 
});
```

Note: The one important thing here is the scope of `idToClear`,should be available for `button2`  click callback function.

That is the reason  we declared in out side of `button1` click `callback function.`

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/Km7nw/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I think you need this type of functionality.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var IntID;
    $('.box1').click(function () {
       IntID = setInterval(function(){
          $('.arrow').css("top", "-=20px");
       }, 400);
       //clicking on box2 must clearInterval
    });

    $('.box2').click(function () {
         clearInterval(IntID);
 });
});
```